# GetString from Custom Database Resource

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, culture

I used following article for using custom resources from database.

http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-store-strings-in-database-or-xml.aspx
I am trying to get a string resource using this code:

```
string key = "Partner_Key";
        string title = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(typeof(MyDBResources)).GetString(key);
```

But I get error as :

> An exception of type
>   'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not find any resources appropriate for
>   the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "MyResources.MyDBResources.resources" was correctly embedded or
>   linked into assembly "[ProjectName]" at compile time, or that all the
>   satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

The Resource provider code is like:

```
   namespace MyResources {
            public class MyDBResources {
                private static IResourceProvider resourceProvider = new DbResourceProvider();

    public static string Partner_Key {
                   get {
                       return (string) resourceProvider.GetResource("Partner_Key", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name);
                   }
                }
---
}
```

Other side,  the Database resource table has values for all keys.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no direct method to get the string resource by key name, I just inherit the Resource class by new class "ResxExtended" and added a method:

```
public class ResxExtended : MyDBResources
    {
        private static IResourceProvider resourceProvider = new DbResourceProvider();

        public static string GetStringResx(string resourcekey)
        {

            return (string)resourceProvider.GetResource(resourcekey, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name);

        }

    }
```

Then simply from view we use:

```
  string title = [project].[namespace].ResxExtended.GetStringResx("PartnerKey");
```

It is working now.